# Weird behaviour when debugging C programs in Eclipse using GDB

Tags: c, eclipse, debugging, gdb

I was trying to debug a C program that requires user inputs, using Eclipse IDE and GDB debugger. Every time I entered a user input in the console, my input was displayed twice. In other words, my input was echoed with the same value. For example, if I debug the following C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int length, width, height;

    printf("Enter length: ");
    scanf("%d", &length);
    printf("Enter width: ");
    scanf("%d", &width);
    printf("Enter height: ");
    scanf("%d", &height);
    printf("Volume = %d\n", length*width*height);

    return 0;
}
```

, then the console will look something like this:

```
Enter length: 2
2
Enter width: 3
3
Enter height: 4
4
Volume = 24
```

.

As you can see, the values 2, 3 and 4 are displayed twice respectively. Running this program (instead of debugging) gives the expected result:

```
Enter length: 2
Enter width: 3
Enter height: 4
Volume = 24
```

In addition, I notice that the execution of `printf()` statements are delayed: although I have already clicked "step over", there is nothing shown in the console. To make this issue more obvious, let us change the code to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int length, width, height;

    printf("Enter length: ");
    printf("Enter length: "); // newly added line
    printf("Enter length: "); // newly added line
    scanf("%d", &length);
    printf("Enter width: ");
    scanf("%d", &width);
    printf("Enter height: ");
    scanf("%d", &height);
    printf("Volume = %d\n", length*width*height);

    return 0;
}
```

In this case, the string "Enter length: Enter length: Enter length: " will be displayed all at once, after I stepped over line 9: `scanf("%d", &length);`. However, if I add a new line character '\n' at the end every time I call `printf()`, then there will be no problem and the strings will be immediately printed to the console.

I know that these two issues are trivial, but being OCD I really want to know what is going on here. I guess it has something to do with how Eclipse handles input and output? But then again I don't see these issues when debugging java programs in Eclipse.

PS. I am running on Mac OS X El Capitan, Eclipse (Mars) IDE for C/C++ Developers, and I installed GDB with Homebrew according to the instruction given here: http://ntraft.com/installing-gdb-on-os-x-mavericks/.

Thanks in advance for answering.

Comment: Try a better IDE: CLion from JetBrains.  I don't understand why anybody uses Eclipse.

Comment: @duffymo: Because it's free? :) I use Eclipse for java so I tried their C/C++ version. I actually use text editors like Sublime Text for C/C++..

Comment: It's the only reason I ever used it.  Glad I learned about something better.

Comment: If you're on mac, can't you use x-code? Otherwise, have a look at Qt creator.

Comment: In the Run Configurations window, is there a checkbox labeled *Connect process input & output to a terminal*? Is it checked?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, I don't see such checkbox. I am using Eclipse IDE for C/C++ developers (Mars version for Mac OS).

Comment: I guess mars doesn't have that option. Will look to see if there's some option that may be inadvertently not giving your program a terminal for its i/o.

Answer (score 1):

The output is being buffered. A new line character flushes the buffer and displays the result on the screen. That's why you're not having the issule when you add `\n`.

Alternatively, you can try adding `fflush(stdout);` after your printf statements.

Also, I would also suggest you to use Xcode for Mac instead of Eclipse.